# Use Branch.io for analytics in react native

Tags: react-native, analytics, branch.io

I am working on integrating branch.io in react-native project for analytics.
Able to see the events getting registered in branch.io dashboard, using BranchEvent() method.

Also want each users id to show up for analytics in branch.io dashboard. So using branch.setIdentity(userId). But not able to see it in dashboard. Am I doing it wrong ?
Is it possible to show user id as well with event in branch.io dashboard for analytics
This userId is unique id of user.

Answer (score 1):

You can view your userId for each event by going to Liveview tab of your Branch Dashboard.

Make sure to enable 'developer identity' from list of columns to show, since the ID set by setIdentity() method is shown under developer identity field.